# How to sort a list by another list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a `list` and a `order`

```
list = {{{357, 120}, {271, 78}}, {{239, 90}, {259, 77}}, {{259, 
     71}, {165, 25}}, {{271, 70}, {337, 30}}};
order = {{259, 77}, {259, 71}, {271, 78}, {271, 70}};
```

So any beautiful method to sort the `list` by `order`?The current method is look sounds clumsy:

```
Catenate@MapThread[
  Complement, {Catenate[Select[list, MemberQ[#]] & /@ order], 
   List /@ order}]
```

> {{239, 90}, {165, 25}, {357, 120}, {337, 30}}

Comment: Could you clarify exactly how the input and output are related? It appears that the `list` is a list of pairs, and the `order` contains one element from each pair in some order, and you want the corresponding element from all of those pairs in `list`, is that correct?

Comment: @MartinBüttner The `list`'s every element (list of pairs) contain a element of `order`.

Comment: Belated Happy 10K!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks. It is not too easy for me indeed. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, something like this would work:

```
list = {{{357, 120}, {271, 78}}, {{239, 90}, {259, 77}}, {{259, 
     71}, {165, 25}}, {{271, 70}, {337, 30}}};
order = {{259, 77}, {259, 71}, {271, 78}, {271, 70}};

SelectFirst[
  SelectFirst[list, MemberQ[#]],
  UnequalTo[#]
] & /@ order

(* {{239, 90}, {165, 25}, {357, 120}, {337, 30}} *)
```

The inner `SelectFirst` picks out the pair from `list` which contains the current element in `order`. The outer `SelectFirst` then chooses the element which is not equal to the one in `order`.

As Jason B points out, `UnequalTo` is a new addition in 10.4. In 10.3 you could use `Not @* EqualTo[#]` instead, but before that you'll have to use a closure or something like that:

```
With[{elem = #},
  SelectFirst[
    SelectFirst[list, MemberQ[#]],
    # != elem &
  ]
] & /@ order
```

Alternatively, a simple pattern-based approach:

```
FirstCase[list, {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@ order

(* {{239, 90}, {165, 25}, {357, 120}, {337, 30}} *)
```

This second approach is actually a bit faster, in case you want to handle large lists:

```
list = RandomInteger[400, {2000, 2, 2}];
order = RandomSample[RandomChoice /@ list];
RepeatedTiming[
  SelectFirst[
    SelectFirst[list, MemberQ[#]],
    UnequalTo[#]
  ] & /@ order;
]
(* {4.04, Null} *)

RepeatedTiming[
  FirstCase[list, {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@ order;
]
(* {2.682, Null} *)
```

Comment: God!How terse(I just now learned this word) the code is!

Comment: In case you are using version 10.3, you need to replace `UnequalTo[#]` with `Not@*EqualTo[#]`.  If before 10.3, probably another construction is needed

Comment: @JasonB Oh good point. In that case I might just go with a closure and do `elem != # &`. I'll edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two variants on the same idea of using [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html).  The first is a little faster on small lists and on large lists.  They're about the same on @Martin Ender's example in his answer.

```
Flatten[Nearest[Join[#1, #2] -> Join[#2, #1] & @@ Transpose@list,
  order, {1, 0}], 1]
Flatten[Nearest[Flatten[list, 1] -> Flatten[Reverse /@ list, 1],
  order, {1, 0}], 1]
(*
  {{239, 90}, {165, 25}, {357, 120}, {337, 30}}
  {{239, 90}, {165, 25}, {357, 120}, {337, 30}}
*)
```

Timings on @Martin Ender's example.  Note that the uniqueness of the result depends on the uniqueness of the sorting keys in `order`.  For `RandomInteger[400, {2000, 2, 2}]` with `SeedRandom[0]`, the keys were not unique, so I increased the size of the integers to make them so.

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[4000, {2000, 2, 2}];
order = RandomSample[RandomChoice /@ list];

foo1 = Flatten[
    Nearest[Join[#1, #2] -> Join[#2, #1] & @@ Transpose@list, 
     order, {1, 0}], 1]; // RepeatedTiming

foo2 = Flatten[Nearest[Flatten[list, 1] -> Flatten[Reverse /@ list, 1],
     order, {1, 0}], 1]; // RepeatedTiming

foo3 = FirstCase[list, {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@  (* Martin Ender's faster one *)
    order; // RepeatedTiming

foo1 == foo2 == foo3

(*
  {0.0024, Null}
  {0.0024, Null}
  {1.955, Null}
  True
*)
```

---

*Addendum.*
Note that part of the slowness of `FirstCase` is that it unpacks `list` (repeatedly). A single unpacking of `list` does not take that much time compared to the overall time.  It makes a difference whether the call to `FirstCase[]` is by reference to the stored array, `listup` below, or is directly on the output of `FromPackedArray`.  It seems in the latter case, the array is repacked and we're back to situation above, `FirstCase[list,...]`.  Even weirder is the case where the array is unpacked to level 1.  There were many warnings from `On@"Packing"` of unpacking to level 1, so I thought I'd see if an unpacked list of packed arrays might be faster.  Instead it was much slower.  Further, it depends on how it's unpacked, whether it's unpack and repacked at level 1 or simply unpacked with `{##} & @@ list`.  The unpacking and repacking takes very little time. I'm not sure why the speed is so slow, but I thought it was worth pointing out.  There is a similar difference whether `FirstCase[]` is called on an array stored in a symbol or the direct output of a function.

```
(* Completely unpacked *)
(listup = Developer`FromPackedArray@list;
   FirstCase[listup, {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@ order); // RepeatedTiming
FirstCase[Developer`FromPackedArray[list], {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@
    order; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.604, Null}
  {1.9, Null}
*)

(* Unpacked to level 1 *)
(murf = {##} & @@ list;   (* store in murf *)
   FirstCase[murf, {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@ order); // RepeatedTiming
FirstCase[                (* not stored in variable *)
     {##} & @@ list,
     {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@ order; // RepeatedTiming
FirstCase[                (* unpacked & repacked below level 1 *)
     With[{opts = SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]},
      Internal`WithLocalSettings[
       SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> Infinity],
       Developer`ToPackedArray /@ Developer`FromPackedArray[list],
       SetSystemOptions[opts]
       ]],
     {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@ order; // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {1.37, Null}
  {2.0, Null}
  {5.7, Null}
*)
```

Comment: `Lookup[AssociationThread[Join[#1, #2] -> Join[#2, #1] & @@ Transpose@list], order]` is a little slower than the `Nearest` solution, taking a little less than twice as long.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that, Michael E2. Super impressive performance with `Nearest[ ]`!

Sharing this for information, as an experiment with `SortBy[ ]`. Starting with the big data set

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[4000, {2000, 2, 2}];
order = RandomSample[RandomChoice /@ list];
```

Tried the problem using `SortBy[ ]` and here is the kernel of it (skipping the bookwork on picking off the non-matching elements)

```
SortBy[list, (Position[order, #[[1]] |  #[[2]]]) &]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> 1.9

Most of that was computing the Position, it appears

```
Map[(Position[order, #[[1]] |  #[[2]]]) &, list]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> 1.887

Here's my full version and Martin Enders' The `Nearest` version is too cheap to meter.

```
foo3 = FirstCase[list, {a_, #} | {#, a_} :> a] & /@(*Martin Ender's faster one*)
order; // RepeatedTiming

foo4 = MapThread[(Complement[#1, {#2}] // First) &, 
                     {SortBy[list, (Position[order,#[[1]] | #[[2]]]) &],order}
                ]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> 2.12
>
> 1.87