# Select with test function that depends on #

Tags: function-construction, pure-function

I'm trying to teach myself to use pure functions and slots as much as possible.
Here is my problem.

I have a list:

```
RandomSeed[314];
l = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20]
(*{3, 6, 1, 4, 4, 6, 1, 6, 3, 6, 8, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 8, 4, 4, 8}*)
```

Now I want to select all elements that equal 1 by using `Select`:

```
Select[l, # == 1 &]
(*{1, 1}*)
```

Then I want to get two lists, one with 8s and second with 1s:

```
test[p_] := p == # &;
Select[l, test[#]] & /@ {8, 1}
(*{{8, 8, 8, 8}, {1, 1}}*)
```

How can I do it without introducing `test[p_]`?
In other words I need `Select`'s second argument to depend on "another" slot `#`, not the one that will be substituted by list elements during iteration. The closest question I was able to find is [Second level depth pure function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16947/second-level-depth-pure-function), but I think my question is slightly different, because I don't have to put slot in the first argument of `Select`

> **Update:** Answers extracted from comments.

Thanks a lot to everybody who answered in comments.

```
leo[l_] := Reap[Sow[#, #] & /@ l, 1 | 8, #2 &][[2]];
jm[l_] := Function[p, Select[l, # == p &]] /@ {8, 1};
kgl[l_] := Select[l, Function[x, x == #]] & /@ {8, 1};
mar[l_] := With[{p = #}, Select[l, # == p &]] & /@ {8, 1};
```

Out of curiosity I decided to run simple benchmark to check performance

```
Benchmark[f_, n_] := Module[{l, results, samples},
   RandomSeed[314];
   samples = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 100}, n], {10}]; 
   results = Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[f[l]], {l, samples}];
   Mean[results]];
testRange = 10^# &@{3, 4, 5, 6};
TableForm[
 Table[Benchmark[fun, n]/n, {fun, {leo, jm, kgl, mar}}, {n, 
   testRange}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"leo", "jm", "kgl", "mar"}, testRange}]
```

[image]

The results are normalized over list length.
Interestingly `kgl[]` is about two times slower than `jm[]`.

IMHO the `Select[l, Function[x, x == #]] & /@ {8, 1}` (by @kglr) is the most visually appealing.

It was also asked **why do I care if all I need is just making two simple `Select`s?**

I think it's more clear and concise to have one line that does something twice rather than having two almost identical lines. My original example is oversimplified probably.

Imagine I want to select all prime numbers and also all numbers that are prime squared. If I use syntax by @kglr I can do

```
{primes, primeSq} = 
 Select[l, Function[x, #[x]]] & /@ {PrimeQ, PrimeQ@Sqrt[#] &}
```

Which is very self explanatory.

Comment: `With[{p=#}, Select[l, # == p &]]& /@{8,1}` is one possibility. Or use `Function`.

Comment: Why not `Function[p, Select[l, # == p &]] /@ {8, 1}`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, @J.M.  It still kinda introduces a named parameter and also wraps my function into something. I'm more after some sort of `#` slot of upper level?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Yes, I mentioned it in my question. My question is different because the first argument in `Select` is the same in my case. So I was hoping that my question has simpler solution.

Comment: Note that in some cases (depending on what `test`) is, you can use an operator form like `EqualTo[#]`. [Here is such an example from earlier today.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110385/2305)

Comment: I retracted the close vote. However, note that as soon as you start categorizing things, your operation is no longer a simple select, so there is no reason to expect that `Select` without additional steps can handle it - categorization is semantically different from selection. You can use `Reap` and `Sow` with specific tags: `Reap[Sow[#, #] & /@ l, 1 | 8, #2 &][[2]]`, which maps mor directly to your needs, it seems.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The `Reap Sow` approach doesn't conserve order - it gives `{{1, 1}, {8, 8, 8, 8}}` instead of `{{8, 8, 8, 8}, {1, 1}}`. Also I think it's way more complex than `Function[p, Select[l, # == p &]] /@ {8, 1}`

Comment: @BlacKow  `Reap` - `Sow` is a conceptually simpler solution, and also with much better complexity, if you look for a categorization problem (which you do, de facto). OTOH, if all you need is a couple of selections, then I don't see why asking this question at all. As I said, your problem is really *not* a  pure selection problem as soon as you start combining elements into groups.  If `Map` and `Select` work for you - fine.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This is not about `Select` really, instead of `Select` there could be any other function that takes pure function as an argument. Honestly I was hoping that I'm missing some magic syntax a la "&_#_" that would be identical  to  `Function[p, Select[l, # == p &]]`

Comment: `Select[l, Function[x, x == #]] & /@ {8, 1}`?

Comment: @BlacKow I don't think your real problem is syntactic. You may *think* that it is, but I think it is really semantic. Which is what I tried to convey in my previous comments.

Comment: @BlacKow, from the `Slot` docs: "When pure functions are nested, the meaning of slots may become ambiguous, in which case parameters must be specified using an explicit Function construction with named parameters."

Comment: One could think that named slot `#a ,#b...` have been invented to solve this problem (after the doc was written), but it is not the case, not at all.

Comment: @kglr Care to put it as an answer? I like it better than others.

Comment: @BlacKow, just posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = {3, 6, 1, 4, 4, 6, 1, 6, 3, 6, 8, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 8, 4, 4, 8}; 
Select[l, Function[x, x == #]] & /@ {8, 1}
```

> {{8, 8, 8, 8}, {1, 1}}