# Distinguish hashtag # operator when using multiple functions

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, map

I would like to do this

```
list = Append[list[[#]],Map[list2[[1, #]] & , list[[#, 4]], {2}]] & /@ Range[Length[list]];
```

But I would like to substitute `list2[[1,#]]` with `list2[[#,#]` where the first `#` is different from the second one, that is the first `#` refers to the "outer" parameter.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Read [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16947/second-level-depth-pure-function) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110437/select-with-test-function-that-depends-on) and read documentation for `Function`

Comment: Is this what you want? `Append[list[[#]], 
    Map[Function[{x}, list2[[#, x]]], list[[#, 4]], {2}]] & /@ 
  Range[Length[list]];`

Comment: @march exactly! Your solution is working! Thanks